# Чтение и запись в файл с помощью одного потока

Tags: c++, файлы

Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы outfile заменить на infile, т.е. выполнить чтение и запись файла одним объектом. Как мне это сделать?

Вот код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

class Array {
public:
    int Value;
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, const Array& array);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Array& array);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Array& array) {
    is >> array.Value;
    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Array& array) {
    os << array.Value;
    return os;
}


int main() {
    Array classArray[4];

    ifstream infile("vhod.txt"); // создает объект ifstream
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        infile >> classArray[i];

    ifstream outfile("vhod.txt"); //создать объект ofstream
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        outfile << classArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этих целей в стандартной библиотеке существует [std::fstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{ 
    std::fstream file("vhod.txt");
    file << 10;
    int a = 0;
    file >> a;
    std::cout << "a = " << a << "\n";
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

---

`std::fstream` является слиянием `std::ifstream` и `std::ofstream`. С помощью объектов `std::fstream` можно выполнять как чтение, так и запись из/в файл. Это один из примеров полезного использования множественного наследования.

Comment: Как ни странно, от `{i|o}fstream` он не наследуется: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, напрямую `fstream` не наследуется. Это делает `iostream`. В результате более высокая гибкость потоков. Суть остается та же: поток, предназначенный для ввода и вывода образуется путем слияния потока ввода и потока вывода.

Answer (score 2):

создайте объект fstream а не ifstream

```
fstream file ("vhod.txt"); // создайте объект fstream а не ifstream
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        file >> classArray[i];        
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        file << classArray[i];
```